# De un Arreglo con números aleatorios, como sacar el numero menor

Tags: java, array, switch

En el colegio el profesor de programación, nos dejo de tarea un mini proyecto, que consiste en hacer 15 ejercicios mediante un menú y nos dijo que los ejercicios que no pudiéramos hacer los investigáramos nosotros por nuestra cuenta, agradecería que me orientaran con la practica, cualquier duda o mejora en el código con gusto responderé.

el ejercicio 13 dice así:
De un arreglo con números aleatorios, como sacar el numero menor.

Este es el código realizado:

```
int l = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo"));
int[] arreglo = new int[l];
int menor = 0;
for (int low = 0; low < arreglo.length; low++) {
  if (arreglo[low] < menor) {
      menor = arreglo[low];
  }
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El arreglo es: \n" + impresion + "\n" + "El menor es: \n" + menor);
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]. Centra tu pregunta en algún problema en específico: las preguntas muy amplias terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask].

Comment: he formateado tu pregunta para que cumpla con las normas del sitio.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: pero de igual forma este post  no representa ningún problema, o no definiste en tu post el problema o duda que tienes... es importante que lo incluyas saludo, puedes hacerlo dándole en editar

Comment: Al momento de mostrar el mensaje haces uso de la variable **impresion** , no tengo claro que es lo que quiers mostrar como salida aparte del elemento menor

Comment: ¿Donde están los números aleatorios? Si no recuerdo mal, los int se inicializan a 0. Siempre va a salir que el menor es 0 ahí. Y lo de llamar low a la variable contador del bucle for confunde un poco. Mucho mejor sería la clásica i.

Answer (score 4):

No te haré el trabajo, pero daré una idea: supongamos que tenemos una matriz con 10 numeros aleatorios o ingresados por teclado:

```
A()=[21,12,15,34,3.14,1.9,2,71, etc ]
```

Un numero es menor o mayor?, si no hay contra quien comparar entonces no se puede dar una respuesta , por lo tanto necesitamos 2 valores para comparar,
nuestro Array tiene 10 elementos, por lo tanto i=10;
luego definimos el primer valor del array A(1) como el menor, entonces definimos una variable auxiliar en donde guardaremos nuestro valor menor, entonces aux=A(1); o sea aux=21; entonces nuestro valor menor inicial es 21, luego tendremos que recorrer la matriz completa, a excepción del primer elemento ya que ya sabemos cual es.

```
$aux = A(1);
for($i=1;$i<9;$i++){
}
```

luego dentro del ciclo debemos hacer la comparación con el elemento y si es menor que el ya asignado entonces hay un nuevo menor y ese será el siguiente elemento a comparar hasta completar el ciclo FOR

```
if( A($i) < $aux){
   // entonces aux ya no es el menor y asignamos el nuevo menor
   $aux=A($i);
} else {
   // de lo contrario aux sigue siendo el menor y no hacemos nada
}
```

Ahora ya con nuestro pseudocodigo ya tenemos el procedimiento completo.

```
   $aux = A(1);
   for($i=1;$i<9;$i++){
    if( A($i) < $aux){
       // entonces aux ya no es el menor y asignamos el nuevo menor
       $aux=A($i);
     } else {
       // de lo contrario aux sigue siendo el menor y no hacemos nada
    }   
   } // fin del for
   echo "el Numero menor es : ".$aux;
```

Answer (score 2):

Según el título; quieres generar la cantidad de números aleatorios que pides que ingresen por teclado, luego quieres mostrar los números aleatorios generados y cual ha sido el menor número generado.
En el código que compartes en ninguna linea generas los números aleatorios.
Te comparto el código de lo que pides comentado

```
int l = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo"));         
              
        ArrayList<Integer> arreglo=new ArrayList();
        int numero;
        for (int i = 0; i <l; i++) { 
            numero=(int)(Math.random()*l+1); //generar números aleatorios entre 1 y L  
             arreglo.add(numero);//agregamos el número aleatorio al arreglo
        }    
        Collections.sort(arreglo);//Ordenamos las numeros aleatorios 
        
        //mostramos los números aleatorios generados
        for (Integer n : arreglo) {
            System.out.println(n + "");
        }      
              
        System.out.println("\nMenor elemento del arreglo: "+arreglo.get(0));
```

Answer (score -1):

En java 8 la forma mas eficiente de manipular listas de datos es usar los Stream. Para aplicar esto en el código que indicas quedaría así:

```
// Instanciar clase Random
Random random = new Random();

//ingresa el rango del arreglo
int tamaño = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo"));

//genera la lista de números aleatorios entre 1 y 100
IntStream intStream = random.ints(tamaño, 1, 100);

//Se convierte el IntStream en un LIST para poder manipularla
List<Integer> numeros = intStream.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

//sacamos el menor de la lista
int menor = numeros.stream().min((i, j) -> i.compareTo(j)).get();

//Presenta el resultado
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El arreglo es: \n" + numeros.toString() + "\n" + "El menor es: \n" + menor);
```

Debes estudiar los [lambda expression](https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/lambda-expressions/)  ya que en casi todos los lenguajes actuales es lo mas utilizado, en java la anotación es "->"

Comment: El ejercicio está claramente definido para usar un array. Los estudiantes no pueden emplear estructuras de datos más complejas hasta que no se las hayan impartido o se lo permitan. Esto no responde a la pregunta.